# Comparing elements of two lists and dictionaries without explicitly iterating over each element

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I would like to compare each element in two lists (e.g. whether each element in a is larger than or equal to each element in b at the same index), and wonder if there is a faster way than doing iteration.
E.g.

```
import random
import time
a = [random.randint() for i in range(10**7)]
b = [random.randint() for i in range(10**7)]
```

I would like to know if there is a faster way than this:

```
start = time.time()
for i in range(10**7):
   if a[i] < b[i]: 
       continue
   else: 
       print('Nope')
       break
end = time.time()
print('%.100f' %(end-start))
Out:
Nope
0.0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

Following suggestions from answers below, this is the time it took using numpy

```
start = time.time()
al = np.all(np.array(b) > np.array(a))
end = time.time()
print('%.100f' %(end-start))
Out:
1.6209998130798339843750000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

How about comparing keys in dictionaries? Same as above, but instead of comparing elements of lists, we compare keys of dictionaries.

Thank you!

Comment: you could make `a` and `b` in a for loop and check the two random values before/after appending and then set a flag if not true...like `for _ in range(10**5): ta=random.randint() tb=random.randint() if ta>=tb: nope=True a.append(ta) b.append(tb)`

Comment: You're already `O(n)`, it will be hard to do better. Except doing as @depperm said

Comment: python loops are quite slow, he can avoid using python loops

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`import numpy as np`.

```
al = np.all(np.array(b) > np.array(a))
```

Output

```
al will be true if each element in a > each element in b
```

---

```
import time
import numpy as np

lst1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 6]
lst2 = [4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 9]
lst3 = [3, 5, 6, 6, 7, 7, 1]


def function1(a, b):
    start = time.clock()
    al = np.all(np.array(b) > np.array(a))
    print("%f" % (time.clock() - start))


def function2(a, b):
    start = time.clock()
    for i in range(7):
        if a[i] < b[i]:
            continue
        else:
            print('Nope')
            break
    print("%f" % (time.clock() - start))


function1(lst1, lst2) #0.000046
function2(lst1, lst2) #0.000002
function1(lst1, lst3) #0.000011
function2(lst1, lst3) #0.000005
```

---

O(n) is faster.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to compare each pair-wise element, you're going to have to iterate, and your current algorithm is already `O(n)`, as pointed out in the comments.

However, using generators, you can reduce the total number of operations. Specifically, to create the two lists, you perform 2 * 10^5 operations, regardless of whether your predicate (`a[i] < b[i]`) will ever fail. With generators, you will only create list elements as needed, so there is no initial 2 * 10^5 cost.

```
import random
a = (random.randint() for _ in range(10**5))
b = (random.randint() for _ in range(10**5))
```

So far, we've only performed 2 operations in total.

```
for i in range(10**5):
    if next(a) < next(b):
        continue
    else:
        print('Nope:', i)
        break
```

Now, we're technically performing more operations per loop, but the total operational cost will only ever reach the original (using basic lists) once the generators are exhausted (i.e. in the case when `a[i]` is never greater than or equal to `b[i]`).

Comment: I believe this is faster because of the `break` statement that means it does not compare the full list, but only until the first time an element in b is greater than a. Numpy does have a bit of overhead though, so it is more worth while for larger arrays (but at least for me, arrays of size 10**5 are performing faster in numpy than this)

Answer (score 1):

You can use numpy to do this. Just load in the lists as arrays and then compare them. Numpy is mostly written in C and makes these operations much faster than pure python

```
import numpy as np
import random

a = np.array([random.randint(0, 10) for i in range(10**5)])
b = np.array([random.randint(0, 10) for i in range(10**5)])

a >= b
```

output:
`array([False, False, False, ...,  True,  True,  True], dtype=bool)`

the dictionaries are more complicated because they are not ordered. You can try making an ordered dictionary, get the values, and then reuse the above method

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you need to iterate to retrieve the elements that you need to compare from the lists in your example.

A better way to would be:

```
for x, y in zip(a,b): 
    if x < y: 
        continue  
    else: 
        print('Nope')
        break
```

A *faster* way would be:

```
if a > b: print("nope")
```

This is exactly what you're doing in your code, comparing every element in `a` with every element in`b`, if any element in `a` is greater than the corresponding element in `b`, print `"nope"` and exit. This is also what the comparison operator does.